# How to get the minikube ip virtual machine address within a container running inside minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I need to get the minikube ip address from inside a container running inside the minikube cluster. Currently I am using an environment variable which is set before the pod is launched. I DO NOT want to use this because the ip address can change. I need someway of dynamically obtaining the ip address of the virtual machine that the minikube virtual machine is running on.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can give some context and explain why you want to do this? Generally, something inside the cluster wouldn't go out to its own external IP address to communicate with another service.

Comment: I want to run a dns service for all the Ingresses in the cluster

Answer (score 0):

My current solution / workaround is to use a helm chart for the service I want to provide the ip to then when I install / update the chart I use `--set minikubeIP=$(minikube ip)` then that helm chart has a hard coded environment with the minikube ip for the the pod that needs the minikube ip. Not really ideal but it works.